# c# repater from JSON without class

Tags: c#, vb.net, asprepeater

Im new to c# i come from a basic vb knowledge so im still learning.

The question is: I have a json whit some var (name, tlf, email) that i read and show trought a repeater.
In VB i can read this with newtonsoft and then bind to a repeater, no need to make a class whit such properties.

But in c# i have to make a class to make it work.

Its something i miss? Thanks

```
private class JsonFooterDatos
    {
        private string name;
        private string tlf;
        private string email;        

        public string Name{ get {return name; }}
        public string Tlf { get {return tlf; }}
        public string Email { get {return email; }}
    }
    public void RellenarFooter()
    {
        LecturaXML.Apartado apartado = new LecturaXML.Apartado();
        LecturaXML.LeerApartadoXML("2530", ref apartado);

        if (apartado.Id != "")
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken>(apartado.Html);
            dirFooter.DataSource = result;
            dirFooter.DataBind();
        }
    }
protected void DirFooterProvincia(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
//

HERE WHY I HAVE TO CAST TO THIS CLASS IN C# BUT NOT IN VB

 -->> //           var di = (JsonFooterDatos)e.Item.DataItem;
//IF I DONT DO THE CAST e.Item.DataItem.email WILL FAIL WITH CS1061 BUT IN VB IT WORKS
            if (di.Name.ToString().ToUpper() != di.Email.ToString().ToUpper())
                e.Item.FindControl("Provincia").Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

VB Code that works

```
  Sub RellenarFooter()
        Dim apartado As LecturaXML.Apartado = New LecturaXML.Apartado
        LecturaXML.LeerApartadoXML("2444", apartado)

        If apartado.Id <> "" Then
            Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Linq.JToken)(apartado.Html)
            dirFooter.DataSource = result
            dirFooter.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub DirFooterProvincia(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs)
        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then
            If e.Item.DataItem("email").ToString.ToUpper <> e.Item.DataItem("name").ToString.ToUpper Then
                e.Item.FindControl("Provincia").Visible = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

JSON

```
[
    {
        "Name": "OFICINA DE EMPRESAS 1",
        "Tlf": "947 11 11 11 ",
        "Email": "xx@xx.com"
    },
    {
        "Name": "OFICINA DE EMPRESAS 2",
        "Tlf": "947 11 11 11 ",
        "Email": "xx@xx.com"
    },
    {
        "Name": "OFICINA DE EMPRESAS 3",
        "Tlf": "947 11 11 11 ",
        "Email": "xx@xx.com"
    }
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't really need to make a class, you could use anonymous types and the such.  My advise is just define a class.  Makes everything down stream of your deserilization much more straight forward

Comment: Why are you making the properties of your `JsonFooterDatos` class `read only`?  As written, you have no way of setting them or the backing fields. Even if you want them to be readonly, you can still implement them as _auto-properties_.  For example: `public string Name{ get; private set; }`.  That way, you can set them in a constructor or other method

Comment: @Flydog57 i dont want the class. Its there because if not it wont compile

Comment: *BUT IN VB IT WORKS* - that's probably because, by default, VB plays much faster and looser with type safety, compile time checking, data conversions etc as a legacy throwback to appeal to the generally more sloppy ways of coding that VB6 allowed. It's not a good thing. Just make the cast - you'll hopefully come to love the more rigorous, structured way of coding C# brings that means your apps don't inexplicably die in a heap at runtime. You can at least be thankful that casting in C# needs just a pair of brackets; nowhere near the exercise in verbosity that `DirectCast(...)` is in VB

Comment: Perhaps you could post your working VB code and some of your JSON.  You may find that deserializing into a `dynamic` is somewhat equivalent to what you are seeing in your VB code (`var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(yourJson);`)

Comment: At the end i made a class., but for future people, i post the vb code and a json